# Bluetooth OBEX FTP server on Android 2.X

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, obex, bluecove

I'm using the Bluecove library to devolep an Obex ftp client/server on android 2.X.
So far i managed to connect as a client from android to a pc.
I tried the bluecove example code for a server but doesn't work.
Is it possible to develop a server on android 2.X. Does any one have the code to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OBEXServer implements Runnable {

    private SessionNotifier serverConnection;

    private boolean isStoped = false;

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public final UUID OBEX_OBJECT_PUSH = new UUID(0x1105);

    public static final String SERVER_NAME = "OBEX Object Push";

    private UserInteraction interaction;

    private OBEXServer(UserInteraction interaction) {
        this.interaction = interaction;
    }

    public static OBEXServer startServer(UserInteraction interaction) {
        OBEXServer srv = new OBEXServer(interaction);
        Thread thread = new Thread(srv);
        thread.start();
        while (!srv.isRunning && !srv.isStoped) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new Error(e);
            }
        }
        if (!srv.isRunning) {
            throw new Error("Can't start server");
        }
        return srv;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run() {
        isStoped = false;
        LocalDevice localDevice;
        try {
            localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            if (!localDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC)) {
                Logger.error("Fail to set LocalDevice Discoverable");
            }
            serverConnection = (SessionNotifier) Connector.open("btgoep://localhost:" + OBEX_OBJECT_PUSH + ";name="
                    + SERVER_NAME);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.error("OBEX Server start error", e);
            isStoped = true;
            return;
        }

        try {
            ServiceRecord record = localDevice.getRecord(serverConnection);
            String url = record.getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
            Logger.debug("BT server url: " + url);

            final int OBJECT_TRANSFER_SERVICE = 0x100000;

            try {
                record.setDeviceServiceClasses(OBJECT_TRANSFER_SERVICE);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Logger.debug("setDeviceServiceClasses", e);
            }

            DataElement bluetoothProfileDescriptorList = new DataElement(DataElement.DATSEQ);
            DataElement obbexPushProfileDescriptor = new DataElement(DataElement.DATSEQ);
            obbexPushProfileDescriptor.addElement(new DataElement(DataElement.UUID, OBEX_OBJECT_PUSH));
            obbexPushProfileDescriptor.addElement(new DataElement(DataElement.U_INT_2, 0x100));
            bluetoothProfileDescriptorList.addElement(obbexPushProfileDescriptor);
            record.setAttributeValue(0x0009, bluetoothProfileDescriptorList);

            final short ATTR_SUPPORTED_FORMAT_LIST_LIST = 0x0303;
            DataElement supportedFormatList = new DataElement(DataElement.DATSEQ);
            // any type of object.
            supportedFormatList.addElement(new DataElement(DataElement.U_INT_1, 0xFF));
            record.setAttributeValue(ATTR_SUPPORTED_FORMAT_LIST_LIST, supportedFormatList);

            final short UUID_PUBLICBROWSE_GROUP = 0x1002;
            final short ATTR_BROWSE_GRP_LIST = 0x0005;
            DataElement browseClassIDList = new DataElement(DataElement.DATSEQ);
            UUID browseClassUUID = new UUID(UUID_PUBLICBROWSE_GROUP);
            browseClassIDList.addElement(new DataElement(DataElement.UUID, browseClassUUID));
            record.setAttributeValue(ATTR_BROWSE_GRP_LIST, browseClassIDList);

            localDevice.updateRecord(record);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.error("Updating SDP", e);
        }

        try {
            int errorCount = 0;
            int count = 0;
            isRunning = true;
            while (!isStoped) {
                RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler();
                try {
                    count++;
                    Logger.debug("Accepting OBEX connections");
                    handler.connectionAccepted(serverConnection.acceptAndOpen(handler));
                } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
                    isStoped = true;
                    break;
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    if ("Stack closed".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                        isStoped = true;
                    }
                    if (isStoped) {
                        return;
                    }
                    errorCount++;
                    Logger.error("acceptAndOpen ", e);
                    continue;
                }
                errorCount = 0;
            }
        } finally {
            close();
            Logger.debug("OBEX Server finished!");
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        isStoped = true;
        try {
            if (serverConnection != null) {
                serverConnection.close();
            }
            Logger.debug("OBEX ServerConnection closed");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.error("OBEX Server stop error", e);
        }
    }

    private static File homePath() {
        String path = "bluetooth";
        boolean isWindows = false;
        String sysName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        if (sysName != null) {
            sysName = sysName.toLowerCase();
            if (sysName.indexOf("windows") != -1) {
                isWindows = true;
                path = "My Documents";
            }
        }
        File dir;
        try {
            dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    throw new SecurityException();
                }
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            dir = new File(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), System.getProperty("user.name")), path);
        }
        if (isWindows) {
            dir = new File(dir, "Bluetooth Exchange Folder");
        }
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        } else if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            dir.delete();
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return dir;
    }

    private void showStatus(final String message) {
        interaction.showStatus(message);
    }

    private class RequestHandler extends ServerRequestHandler {

        Timer notConnectedTimer = new Timer();

        boolean isConnected = false;

        boolean receivedOk = false;

        Connection cconn;

        void connectionAccepted(Connection cconn) {
            Logger.debug("Received OBEX connection");
            showStatus("Client connected");
            this.cconn = cconn;
            if (!isConnected) {
                notConnectedTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        notConnectedClose();
                    }
                }, 1000 * 30);
            }
        }

        void notConnectedClose() {
            if (!isConnected) {
                Logger.debug("OBEX connection timeout");
                try {
                    cconn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                if (!receivedOk) {
                    showStatus("Disconnected");
                }
            }
        }

        public int onConnect(HeaderSet request, HeaderSet reply) {
            isConnected = true;
            notConnectedTimer.cancel();
            Logger.debug("OBEX onConnect");
            return ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK;
        }

        public void onDisconnect(HeaderSet request, HeaderSet reply) {
            Logger.debug("OBEX onDisconnect");
            if (!receivedOk) {
                showStatus("Disconnected");
            }
        }

        public int onSetPath(HeaderSet request, HeaderSet reply, boolean backup, boolean create) {
            Logger.debug("OBEX onSetPath");
            return super.onSetPath(request, reply, backup, create);
        }

        public int onDelete(HeaderSet request, HeaderSet reply) {
            Logger.debug("OBEX onDelete");
            return super.onDelete(request, reply);
        }

        public int onPut(Operation op) {
            Logger.debug("OBEX onPut");
            try {
                HeaderSet hs = op.getReceivedHeaders();
                String name = (String) hs.getHeader(HeaderSet.NAME);
                if (name != null) {
                    Logger.debug("name:" + name);
                    showStatus("Receiving " + name);
                } else {
                    name = "xxx.xx";
                    showStatus("Receiving file");
                }
                Long len = (Long) hs.getHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH);
                if (len != null) {
                    Logger.debug("file lenght:" + len);
                    interaction.setProgressValue(0);
                    interaction.setProgressMaximum(len.intValue());
                }
                File f = new File(homePath(), name);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                InputStream is = op.openInputStream();

                int received = 0;

                while (!isStoped) {
                    int data = is.read();
                    if (data == -1) {
                        Logger.debug("EOS received");
                        break;
                    }
                    out.write(data);
                    received++;
                    if ((len != null) && (received % 100 == 0)) {
                        interaction.setProgressValue(received);
                    }
                }
                op.close();
                out.close();
                Logger.debug("file saved:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                showStatus("Received " + name);
                receivedOk = true;
                return ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error("OBEX Server onPut error", e);
                return ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_UNAVAILABLE;
            } finally {
                Logger.debug("OBEX onPut ends");
                interaction.setProgressDone();
            }
        }

        public int onGet(Operation op) {
            Logger.debug("OBEX onGet");
            try {
                HeaderSet hs = op.getReceivedHeaders();
                String name = (String) hs.getHeader(HeaderSet.NAME);

                return ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error("OBEX Server onGet error", e);
                return ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_UNAVAILABLE;
            } finally {
                Logger.debug("OBEX onGet ends");
            }
        }

        public void onAuthenticationFailure(byte[] userName) {
            Logger.debug("OBEX AuthFailure " + new String(userName));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just need to implement the specific methods as shown in the specification of the Bluetooth GOEP profile. Simple